# forecast using rugarch in r

Tags: time-series, programming

After fit the GARCH model, I want to plot the volatility forecast sigma series. I use ugarchforecast as follow:

```
fit = ugarchfit(spec, return)`

fore <- ugarchforecast(fit, n.ahead=1, n.roll = 2517, out.sample = 2517)
sigma <- fore@forecast$sigmaFor
```

But there always an error:

```
Error in .sgarchforecast(fitORspec = fitORspec, data = data, n.ahead = n.ahead,  : 

ugarchforecast-->error: n.roll must not be greater than out.sample!
```

what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

n.roll must not be greater than out.sample!

out.sample>n.roll